# How do I encircle branch of tree in Tikz

Tags: graphics, tikz-trees

I was wondering how do I encircle the branch of the tree as shown in the picture.

Here is what I have so far

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,draw,fill=gray]{s}
        child{node[circle,draw,fill=white]{}
             child{node[circle,draw,fill=gray]{}}
        }
        child{node[circle,draw,fill=white]{}
             child{node[circle,draw,fill=gray]{}}
        }
        child{node[circle,draw,fill=white]{}
            child{node[circle,draw,fill=gray]{}}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: tikz tree]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you expand your code to make a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome! There are many ways to draw such a halo, here is one of them.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[halo/.style={line join=round,
 double,line cap=round,double distance=#1,shorten >=-#1/2,shorten <=-#1/2},
 halo/.default=7mm]
    \node[circle,draw,fill=gray](s){s}
        child{node[circle,draw,fill=white]{}
             child{node[circle,draw,fill=gray]{}}
        }
        child{node[circle,draw,fill=white]{}
             child{node[circle,draw,fill=gray]{}}
        }
        child{node[circle,draw,fill=white](R1){}
            child{node[circle,draw,fill=gray](R2){}}
        };
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]     
  \draw[halo] (s) -- (R1.center) -- (R2);       
 \end{scope}
 \path (R2.south) ++ (0,-3.5mm); % shorten does not get taken into account by the bounding box
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful.